# Django searching for objects by criteria

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I know this question is vague but I am hoping it will promt some interesting responses. I am trying to figure out how to accomplish my next Django project and I am having a hard time. I would like to write a Django app that allows someone to enter their information, for example, their age, gender, marital status, etc. and have it return charitable programs that they may qualify for. So here we go:

An organization would create a program and enter in the type of person it is directed towards. Then someone could input their info and have it return what programs they qualify for. The program criteria as well as the user information would be selected by a form ChoiceField. The problem I am having is figuring out how to make the relation between user information and the program criteria. I have a few ideas on how to make this work but I would love to know how a more experienced programmer would handle this task.

Any information/opinions is encouraged. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not an experienced programmer but I think its all about designing the database schema. Have two models:

1. Charitable organizations model: I'll define ChoiceField for the kind of people they want to support and then assign value to each choice. Say there are three kind of patients `i) Trump Fans` `ii) Putin Fans`  `iii) Kim Jong Fans`. Then I'll assign value to each option. `Trump=0`, `Putin=1` and `Kim=3`.
2. `Patients Model`: Define model to collect the information about them and one of the field is to get kind of disability they have.

> ```
> PATIENTS_TYPE = (
>     ('0', 'Trump'),
>     ('1', 'Putin'),
>     ('2', 'Kim'),
>     )
> ```

Once I have this information, all I have to do is to write `if` and `else` statements in views.py to match them.

Comment: Thanks for the info!